# Any way to use Moq to imitate properties of a real-world constructor automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, moq

I've got a controller with a lot of constructor injection:

```
public MoviesController(ISession session, IClientContext clientContext, PManager pManager, ISegmentationService segmentationService, IGeoLocator geoLocator, IBus bus)
{
    _session = session;
    _clientContext = clientContext;
    _pManager = pManager;
    _segmentationService = segmentationService;
    _geoLocator = geoLocator;
    _bus = bus;
}
```

From my understanding (just read about Mocking), I've got a lot of Mock object properties to manually set if I wish to make a comprehensive test suite based on this controller.

For one method I'm only using one service (I'd even like to automate that with little effort if possible):

```
public object Show(Guid id)
{
    var movie = _session.Get<movie>(id);
    return movie;
}
```

But in another there are many services being used - is there any way to set those Moq objects up quickly? I could really use some examples as I'm new to testing. It's an asp.net mvc project with webapi 1 bundled in (testing the webapi controller here)

Comment: You've got to mock the ones which will be used in the function you are testing. If you are using Nunit you can use the `SetUp` method to initialize your service. This method gets executed before every test method, so you don't have to write same code in every test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been said in the comments, if you have common setup code, you can put it in a Setup method that is called automatically from your testing framework before each test.  It's decorated with a `Setup` attribute if you're using Nunit `TestInitialize` if you're using MStest.  If you're using XUnit then [it's a bit different](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2008/01/introduction-to-xunit/).

So, your class might look like this:

```
public class SomeTests {
    Mock<ISession> _sessionMock;
    Mock<IClientContext> _clientContextMock;

    [Setup]
    public void Setup() {
        _sessionMock = new Mock<ISession>();
        _clientContextMock = new Mock <IClientContext();
    }

    MovieController CreateSut() {
        return new MovieController(_sessionMock.Object, _clientContextMock.Object, ...);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestSomething() {
        _sessionMock.Setup(x=>...);

        //...

        var sut = CreateSut();

       //...
    }
}
```

If you're trying to get away from completely creating the mocks manually, then you might want to look at something like [AutoFixture with AutoMoq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoMoq).  Which will automatically supply mock instances when creating objects that accept interfaces.  AutoFixture can be quite useful, but there is a learning curve to using it effectively so you might want to look at a tutorial / quickstart.

You could also configure an IOC container to supply mock instances for your test project, although I've never gone down that route myself.

Comment: Detailed answer thanks.. now I'll try and figure out how to Moq NHibernate from a controller successfully.. (or else let AutoFixture automagically do it for me)

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you only need to mock the session, and can leave all the other dependencies null, since their behaviour should be irrelevant to the behaviour you are testing:

```
Mock<ISession> mockSession = new Mock<ISesssion>();
MoviesController controller = new MoviesController(mockSession.Object, null,null,null,null,null);
```

There is no need for you to set up any mocks other than the ones you need for this particular test

Comment: Fair enough for this particular test, I see that - but what about for say a HttpPost method that employs a lot of them as per above?